# run threads multiple times within process python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Problem description:
I am working with the simulator to extract some dataset from it. The idea is to run multiple processes to perform various task. For example: moving the vehicle using one process and data collection using another process. In the data collection process, 3 threads are running to record three different data types and the recording has to occur periodically. Also, the data should be recorded synchronously.

Sample code is provided without details.

```
import threading 
import multiprocessing
import time

class DataRecorder:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        some parameters
        """
        pass

    def move_vehicle(self, path):
        pass

    def record_data1(self):
        pass

    def record_data2(self):
        pass

    def record_data3(self):
        pass

    def record_data():
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.record_data1)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.record_data2)
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.record_data3)
        threads = [t1, t2, t3]
        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()
        while (True):
           for thread in threads:
               if not thread.is_alive()
                   thread.start()   # leads to threads can only be started once
           for thread in threads:
               if thread.is_alive()
                   thread.join()
           time.sleep(1)

    def stop_recording(self, p1):
        if p1.is_alive():
            p1.terminate()

    def move_and_record():
        P1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.record_data)
        P1.start()
        self.move_vehicle(path)
        self.stop_recording(P1)
```

The problem:

```
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once.
```

And inside while loop, the threads gets stopped after 1st iteration. I have tried both without .join() part and with .join() part.

I am also looking for another alternative to solve this problem.